# Need example for a topological space that isn't (T1,T2,T3), but is (T4)

Tags: general-topology

How can gives me an example for a topological space that : $(T_4)$ but it isn't $(T_3)$ , $(T_4)$ but it isn't $(T_2)$ , $(T_4)$ but it isn't $(T_1)$

Comment: are you sure it is not the other way around  ? Or is it the way you define these concepts, some authors include T1 in the definition of T4, and others don't, and this may be relevant fr at least one part of your question, so please clarify ?

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko The used nomenclature here is that "normal = T4 + T1". So these are somewhat interesting examples.

Comment: Note that if a space is T4 and T1, then it is also T2 and T3. So in all cases, you need a space that is T4 and not T1.

Comment: @DanielFischer Are you sure? Shouldn't what you say imply that T4 and not T2 implies not T1 and T4 and not T3 implies not T1? I think I have an example of a T4, T3 space which is not T1.

Comment: @user2345215 It does imply that. Note that I didn't say that T4 + T3 would imply T1. (it doesn't, any indiscrete space with more than one point is T4 and T3, but not T1)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about two questions more than a question should have on this site. See [MSE faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/214632).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy example that covers all three cases is the [**Nested Interval Topology**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_interval_topology) $\tau$ on $X := (0, 1)$, whose open sets are $0$, $X$, and the intervals $\left(0, 1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. (This is Example 52 in Steen & Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*.)

Every nonempty open set contains, e.g., $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$, so $\tau$ is not $T_0$, and hence is not $T_1$ or $T_2$. Likewise, every neighborhood of the closed set $\left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)$ contains $\frac{1}{3}$, and so $\tau$ is not $T_3$. There are no separated sets, so $\tau$ is vacuously $T_5$ and hence $T_4$.

Comment: @travis this space T4 ?????

Comment: @Maherataturk Every two nonempty closed sets intersect...

Comment: How does $[1/2,1)$ contain $1/3$?

Comment: @Nameless It does not. The claim is that every *neighborhood of $[\frac{1}{2}, 1)$* contains $\frac{1}{3}$: What sets are neighborhoods of that interval?